# ggpmisc Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggpmisc’

Tags: r, ggpmisc

I am trying to use the library ggpmisc and even though the installation went okey it gives me an error when I try to open the library. How can I solve it?

```
install.packages("ggpmisc")
```

> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/ggpmisc_0.4.5.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 1349360 bytes (1.3 MB)
> downloaded 1.3 MB
> package ‘ggpmisc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> C:\Users\dkafe\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpkh620g\downloaded_packages

```
library(ggpmisc)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggpmisc’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘conquer’ In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘ggpmisc’ was built under R version 4.1.3

Comment: the warning shows you may want to install Rtools in windows before installing ggmisc

Comment: I did, but It doesn't seem to fix the problem. Should I use Rtools in some particular way in order to install the package?

Comment: once you install Rtools, maybe update the path env before installing

Comment: So now it fixed the warning, but still gives me an error when I try to open the library Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggpmisc’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘conquer’

Comment: @DimitraK You could try to also install `conquer`. And be sure to restart RStudio or R, as sometimes that can take care of issues like this.

Comment: Yep, that fixed the issue. Thanks allot!!